# Bootstrap datatable Print is not working on second time

Tags: bootstrap-4

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var printCounter = 0;

    // Append a caption to the table before the DataTables initialisation
    $('#example').append('<caption style="caption-side: bottom">A fictional company\'s staff table.</caption>');

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy',
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                messageTop: 'The information in this table is copyright to Sirius Cybernetics Corp.'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                messageBottom: null
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                messageTop: function() {
                    printCounter++;

                    if (printCounter === 1) {
                        return 'This is the first time you have printed this document.';
                    } else {
                        return 'You have printed this document '+printCounter+' times';
                    }
                },
                messageBottom: null
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

I am using below link datatable in my application.

When I click on <kbd>print</kbd> the first time it's working fine and going to the print page, but when I click second or third time it's not going to print.

You can check the same issues in the below link.

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/titleMessage.html

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Do you test this on Chrome ??